# Multiple column update in dataframe from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, data-manipulation

Hi I need to update specific columns in DataFrame based on the dictionary. My initial DataFrame is this

| Date | Var_1 | Var_2 | Var_3 | Var_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 100 | Yes | Yes | 104 |
| 02/01/2022 | 100 | Yes | Yes | 104 |
| 03/01/2022 | 100 | Yes | Yes | 104 |
| 04/01/2022 | 100 | Yes | Yes | 104 |
| 05/01/2022 | 100 | Yes | No | 104 |
| 06/01/2022 | 100 | Yes | No | 104 |
| 07/01/2022 | 100 | Yes | No | 104 |
| 08/01/2022 | 100 | No | Yes | 104 |

and my nested dictionary is this (based on that I need to update this data frame)

```
 my_dict = {
               "01/01/2022" : { "Var_2": "Yes","Var_3": "No"},
               "02/01/2022" : { "Var_2": "Yes","Var_3": "No"},
               "03/01/2022" : { "Var_2": "Yes","Var_3": "Yes"},
               "05/01/2022" : { "Var_2": "No", "Var_3": "Yes"},
               "06/01/2022" : { "Var_2": "No", "Var_3": "Yes"}
              }
```

My desired output would be

| Date | Var_1 | Var_2 | Var_3 | Var_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 100 | Yes | No | 104 |
| 02/01/2022 | 100 | Yes | No | 104 |
| 03/01/2022 | 100 | Yes | Yes | 104 |
| 04/01/2022 | 100 | Yes | Yes | 104 |
| 05/01/2022 | 100 | No | Yes | 104 |
| 06/01/2022 | 100 | No | Yes | 104 |
| 07/01/2022 | 100 | Yes | No | 104 |
| 08/01/2022 | 100 | No | Yes | 104 |

Tried with `.replace(my_dict)` but it didn't worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to convert `my_dict` to a DataFrame and update `df` with it:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index('Date')
tmp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index')
tmp.index = pd.to_datetime(tmp.index)
df.update(tmp)
df = df.reset_index()
```

or use `combine_first`:

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index')
tmp.index = pd.to_datetime(tmp.index)
df = tmp.combine_first(df.set_index('Date')).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Date'})
```

Output:

```
         Date  Var_1 Var_2 Var_3  Var_4
0  01/01/2022    100   Yes    No    104
1  02/01/2022    100   Yes    No    104
2  03/01/2022    100   Yes   Yes    104
3  04/01/2022    100   Yes   Yes    104
4  05/01/2022    100    No   Yes    104
5  06/01/2022    100    No   Yes    104
6  07/01/2022    100   Yes    No    104
7  08/01/2022    100    No   Yes    104
```